# Composition produced a single composition error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use the [MvcPluginFramework](https://mvcpluginframework.codeplex.com/).  I know that it is out of date, but I thought would take a stab at upgrading it. However, I have come across a problem in my code when I try to render the plugin into the view I get the  following exception:

> - $exception  "The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.\r\n\r\n1) Cannot create an instance of type 'PaypalPlugin.PayPalPlugin' because a constructor could not be selected for construction. Ensure that the type either has a default constructor, or a single constructor marked with the 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportingConstructorAttribute'.\r\n\r\nResulting in: Cannot activate part 'PaypalPlugin.PayPalPlugin'.\r\nElement: PaypalPlugin.PayPalPlugin -->  PaypalPlugin.PayPalPlugin -->  DirectoryCatalog (Path=\"C:\Projects\solitudeec2core\solitudeeccore\solitude.admin\solitude.admin\bin\")\r\n\r\nResulting in: Cannot get export 'PaypalPlugin.PayPalPlugin (ContractName=\"Kusog.Mvc.IMvcPlugin\")' from part 'PaypalPlugin.PayPalPlugin'.\r\nElement: PaypalPlugin.PayPalPlugin (ContractName=\"Kusog.Mvc.IMvcPlugin\") -->  PaypalPlugin.PayPalPlugin -->  DirectoryCatalog (Path=\"C:\Projects\solitudeec2core\solitudeeccore\solitude.admin\solitude.admin\bin\")\r\n"  System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException

I am trying to render the html from the controller PayPal so I used the following html helper tag which crashes on this piece of code.

```
/// <summary>
/// Uses MEF to get all plugins defined and get them setup for use in the site.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>This code does not attempt to only call SetupExtensions once for a given plugin.  
/// Each time this method is called, all plugins found will have their SetupExtensions method
/// called.  This is intended to be called once during application startup.</remarks>
protected virtual void refreshPlugins()
{
    try
    {
        m_pluginsContainer = new CompositionContainer(addMefCatalogs(new AggregateCatalog()));
        m_pluginsContainer.ComposeParts(this);
    }
    catch (CompositionException compositionException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(compositionException.ToString());
    }
    catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Exception exSub in ex.LoaderExceptions)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(exSub.Message);
            if (exSub is FileNotFoundException)
            {
                FileNotFoundException exFileNotFound = exSub as FileNotFoundException;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exFileNotFound.FusionLog))
                {
                    sb.AppendLine("Fusion Log:");
                    sb.AppendLine(exFileNotFound.FusionLog);
                }
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        string errorMessage = sb.ToString();
        //Display or log the error based on your application.
    }
    foreach (Lazy<IMvcPlugin, IMvcPluginData> plugin in m_plugins)
    {
        plugin.Value.SetupExtensions(this);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

The following is to show my con-structures for the plugin initialisation

```
using Kusog.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace PayPal.Controllers
{

    [DynamicActionFilter]
    public class PayPalController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("~/Views/Paypal/Index.cshtml");
        }



        public ActionResult PageFooter()
        {
            return Content("");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 3

```
PayPalPlugin.cs 

{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides basic plugin functionality to show how to set it up.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>This plugin inherits from DemoAppPlugin rather than BaseMvcPlugin because it wants to use extended functionality made available in DemoAppPlugin, such as adding menu items.
    /// If a plugin doesn't need to do things other than what is provided in BaseMvcPlugin, it should inherit from that to be usable in other implementations of the plugin framework.</remarks>
    [Export(typeof(Kusog.Mvc.IMvcPlugin))]
    [MvcPluginMetadata("PayPalPlugin", null, "PayPalPlugin", "This is a plugin to be used for Solutide E-Commerce Platform to allow Paypal.")]
    public class PayPalPlugin : DemoAppPlugin
    {
        public override void SetupExtensions(IMvcPluginApplication app)
        {
            base.SetupExtensions(app);

            addLocalCss("/Content/simple.css");
            addFooterScript("ksgSimple", "/Scripts/ksgSimple.js", null);
            AddActionFilter("Index", "PayPalPlugin", new ActionExtension("Index", "PayPal"));

            AddActionFilter("Metatags", "PluginDemo", new ActionExtension("Metatags", "Simple"));

        }
    }
```

Comment: The exception seems to be pretty clear, your `PayPalPlugin` needs to either have a default constructor or a constructor that is mark with the `ImportingConstructorAttribute` attribute.

Comment: @pstrjds do not no why the downvote i understood the error was that but asking how to solve it !

Comment: @pstrjds i have included my code above of the plugin to see what i am missing

Comment: I downvoted because I feel like the question was a bit unclear and you did not provide the information necessary to answer it above saying "you need to add a constructor or an attribute."  As it stands now, you still haven't provided that information, even after my initial comment and now your comment saying that "you understand the error", but you have yet to post the code for the `PayPalPlugin` class which is where the error is coming from. You need to have a default constructor or add an attribute - the error tells you how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried adding an empty constructor in the `PayPalPlugin` class that calls the constructor of the `DemoAppPlugin`. I don't have the bandwidth to setup the demo class and add your code to test this out, otherwise I would try it myself, but that might be all you need to do.

Comment: I found that i was missing the index action was all cause the plugin was requiring it I now have my paypal order button rendering now thanks